# get one field from itab with read table TRANSPORTING

Tags: abap

I trying to get one field from interal table like this:

```
READ TABLE tbl_peps TRANSPORTING ususap INTO lv_responsable WITH KEY usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03.
```

This sentence is wrong, it gives me an error

> tbl_peps and lv_responsable are incompatibles

.

Is there a way to achieve that using "transporting fields"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [ABAP Documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPREAD_TABLE_OUTDESC.htm#&ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@) on `READ TABLE`, if you use the transporting-option the work area receiving the data must be compatible with the line type of the table you read from. Your declared variable `lv_responsable` seems to be incompatible with `tbl_peps`, therefore the error when checking your code.

This should work:

```
DATA:
  wa_peps like line of tbl_peps.

READ TABLE tbl_peps TRANSPORTING ususap INTO wa_peps WITH KEY usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03.  
MOVE wa_peps-ususap TO lv_responsable.
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid work-area, because only one field is needed.

Comment: @Dirk Trilsbeek Are there noticeable benefits of using the TRANSPORTING keyword in the READ TABLE statement. The statement would work with and without it. i.e:
READ TABLE tbl_peps INTO wa_peps WITH KEY usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03.  
  move wa_peps-ususap to lv_responsable.

Comment: @Erik with TRANSPORTING you can chose to transport only a subset of fields into your target structure. For instance if you only want to take a single field and move the value into an already populated work area, keeping the values of other fields in the WA intact. As READ TABLE works on internal tables and is in-memory, I don't think there are any serious performance advantages. Depends of course on the amount of data.

Answer (score 15):

With the new syntax (At least ABAP 7.40) you do not need a workarea anymore. The coding for your example would be:

```
try.
    lv_responsable = tbl_peps[ usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03 ]-ususap.
catch CX_SY_ITAB_LINE_NOT_FOUND.
endtry.
```

Further info of the new table expressions can be found [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2013/05/29/abap-news-for-release-740--table-expressions).

Comment: Excellent contribution

Comment: @funkeeiads If you think this is an excelltent contribution you can uncheck the accepted mark from the other question and put it here.

Answer (score 3):

## Solving the underlying problem

The reason you would want to transport only one field is to save memory and speed up processing. There is a better way to do that, use field symbols:

```
READ TABLE tbl_peps 
  ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_responsable>) 
  WITH KEY usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03.
```

The inline definition only works with ABAP 740 and up, but you can do this in earlier versions:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_responsable> LIKE LINE OF tbl_peps.
READ TABLE tbl_peps 
  ASSIGNING <fs_responsable> 
  WITH KEY usr03 = wa_tbl_prps-usr03.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. `Lv_responsable` has to be defined as follows.

```
DATA: lv_responsable LIKE LINE OF tbl_peps.
```

Only then can you assign the value in field `lv_responsable-ususap` to another variable of the field type.

Comment: I am afraid your right ..
i thought that there was a way not using a work area.